# Search for Youtube videos by town

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube Api v3 and I want to search for video by their city of origin.
But in the [documentation for the filter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), it only covers how to see the videos from a specific country.

How can I narrow the search?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, filtering by town is not supported, we hope to have it back soon.